# Gridview Fixed Header

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, gridview

I have a GridView with about 200 rows and I need to have a fixed header. The header of the page is not fixed.

How can I acheived this using anything: C#, CSS or Javascript/Jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If don't use horizontal scrolling, couldn't you just put the datagrid in a div.
Then create a header div within the datagrid div and with margin-top 0; or something like that.

And just style it with your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=5). It has a lot of amazing features. For your requirement, refer to the "True Scrolling Rows" on the [demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) page (New in version 3.6 segment).

You will also find a couple of asp.net demos

Comment: I need to use asp:GridView control... I mean I already used it, too late to change everything.

Comment: oh! sorry then. i am not much of a asp.net guy